# Is there any middleware that gets called during a request life cycle before going to servlet to get handled?

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

In a normal scenario, the client calls for an HTTP request (get, post, put, etc) and the request goes to the servlet.

To Intercept the request we can define our own filter which can act as middleware.

My question:
Is there any middleware by default inside the javax.servlet package that gets called before the request reaches to target servlet.

Comment: You already answered your own question in your question... The filter is the thing you are looking for.

Comment: But the filter is an interface, is there any class that gets called? i mean i don't want to give implementation for filter interface.

Comment: How else should you provide the code that gets executed. YOu need to implement something.

Comment: I thought there might be a class that implements filter anyways thanks

Comment: Even if there would be, then what? You would have a dummy implementation that doesn't do anything, which you would need to extend and implement the `doFilter` method. So what would be the added benefit?